# How to give a user Admin Rights to only one DNN Portal?

Tags: permissions, dotnetnuke, security-roles, dnn9

How can I give a new user only Admin Rights to one DNN portal?

Currently, we have two portals but I only want to give the users rights to the one portal on DotNetNuke.

Comment: If you use the `Security Roles` manager of that portal and give a user Admin rights, it is limited to that portal only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've described, is in-fact how the "Admin" role works within DNN.

If you are used to the "Host" role, which does span DNN portals, I can see why you'd be confused.

Setting up an Admin user, or any other security role, will only be honoured on that specific portal.

If you want a user to have admin access over multiple portals - They will have to have separate admin accounts.